# Cloud Service Vs Website w.r.t Instances sharing content and configuration

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cloud-services

As mentioned [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm/), one of the differences that caught my eye is "Web server instances share content and configuration, which means you don't have to redeploy or reconfigure as you scale." which is marked NOT possible for cloud services.

If cloud service is set to autoscale/has more instances (scale-out), won't they share the same content (code base I'm assuming) and configuration (*.csdef/.cscfg*) settings?

Answer (score 2):

Azure Cloud Services (web/worker role instances) share code when code is deployed (based on what's in the `.cspkg` along with any content downloaded+installed as instructed in your startup script). Each instance is a fresh VM image, overlaid with your software bits. The same software bits are placed on each scaled instance. They have no shared data space, unless they are attached to something like Azure File Storage (an SMB share atop Azure Storage). Any local disk is per-instance (and non-durable). Any attached drives are per-instance (and durable, backed by Azure Storage).

Azure Web App instances have a shared-disk (durable) between all instances of your web app. This is how, for example, you can run something like Ghost, where the Sqlite database is shared amongst instances. The size of this shared disk area changes based on the App Service Plan tier chosen. Alternatively, Web Apps may access Azure File Storage. Similar to web/worker role instances, every instance of a Web App gets the same code bits deployed.

Comment: _"Alternatively, Web Apps may access Azure File Storage."_ - true, but programatically, not by mounting over SMB, since that's not permitted by the App Service sandbox.

Comment: Right - requires API usage from Web Apps. Thanks for adding the clarification.